# C# for loop create DataGridView and Locate on Form

Tags: c#, datagridview, location

I'm trying to create multiple DataGridViews (DGVs for short) on a Windows Form (C#). I've simplified some of the code like the SQL statement because that stuff already works - so ignore that.

When using specific inputs, this code should produce 6 different DGVs; each placed one after another.

The code lays out all of the DGVs (i think) but they are layered on top of each other. My code for locating each DGV is not working. The DGVs are all located at point (0,0) on my form.

Can someone help point out my error(s)?

```
private void getJobSetpoints(int xID)
    {

        int panelX = 422;
        int panelY = 12;

        int totalHeight = panelY;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            var con = new OleDbConnection(connection.ConnectionString);


            for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
            {

                var select = @"SELECT .........";

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, con);
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = xID;
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CATEGORY", OleDbType.Integer).Value = i;                                   
                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);


                //If data exists then create a DataGridView
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();                        
                    this.Controls.Add(dgv);
                    dgv.Location = new Point(panelX, totalHeight + 30);
                    dgv.Size = new Size(200, 200);
                    dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    dgv.Name = "dgv_" + i;

                    dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    dgv.Visible = true;

                    //Adjust the height of the DataGridView
                    int height = 40;
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
                    {
                        height += dr.Height;
                    }

                    dgv.Height = height;
                    totalHeight += height;                                            

                }
                else { }
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever thought of using a `TabControl`?  You can put each `DataGridView` on a separate `TabPage`.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I might try that.